Can't send a POST request to my web application through postman
This is my first Stack overflow posting.I'm new to the MERN stack and I'm having trouble POSTing raw data to my web application from postman.
The data:
{
    "title": "Situps",
    "load": 0,
    "reps": 50
}

the error I get when i send a POST  request is:
{
    "error": "Operation `workouts.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms"
}

This is the .js file i think may be the culprit:
const express = require('express')
const Workout = require('../models/workoutModel')

const router = express.Router() 

// Get all workouts
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({mssg: 'Get all workouts'})
})

// Get single workout
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    res.json({mssg: 'Get a single workout'})
})

// Post a new workout
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const {title, load, reps} = req.body

    try {
        const workout = await Workout.create({title, load, reps})
        res.status(200).json(workout)
    }   catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({error: error.message})
    }
})

// Delete a workout
router.delete('/:id', (req, res) => {
    res.json({mssg:'Delete a workout'})
})

// Update a workout
router.patch('/:id', (req, res) => {
    res.json({mssg:'Update a workout'})
})

module.exports = router


I figured it out. The issue was i forgot to enter my password into the password field when creating an environment variable to connect my database to my application.
mongodb+srv://Name:password@mernapp.qsskiyi.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=MERNapp
"password" should have been changed to my chosen mongo password
